# Pandas series flatten array to csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have following pandas series

```
0    [1, 11283, 1, 5]
1        [2, 5, 1, 1]
2      [6, 33, 21, 2]
3    [11283, 1, 5, 1]
4     [8430, 1, 2, 2]
5        [2, 1, 1, 1]
```

I need to right this to csv. But I need each item in a list as separate column. For example:
In fist row, 1, 11283, 1, 5 should be separate column

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your series is called `s`, you may create a new DataFrame using `tolist`:

```
out = pd.DataFrame(s.values.tolist())

       0      1   2  3
0      1  11283   1  5
1      2      5   1  1
2      6     33  21  2
3  11283      1   5  1
4   8430      1   2  2
5      2      1   1  1
```

And save to csv.

```
pd.to_csv(out)
```

Comment: @user2805885 added an explanation